# itunesconnect - in app purchase Product ID changed

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've uploaded a Build on itunesconnect and it got passed the review and it's waiting for my release. I mistakenly have deleted the in app purchase products. now i cant reuse the same ID.

What would you guys prefer to do? Do i have to cancel the Build and resend again with the changed code - or is there a different way to solve this issue ?

I didnt tried any steps right now.

Comment: I have no Idea about InApp purchases and very little knowlege of the itunesconnect(I have a app in testflight). This is the first release? If yes Just make an quick update If not cancel and start over. What I would do.

Answer (score 0):

> You have to resend a new build since deleted app products would give
>   **invalid ids** error in storekit now